# Laravel Befriended Column 'id' in where clause is ambiguous

Tags: laravel, join

I am using Laravel [Laravel Befriended](http://www.lib4dev.in/info/rennokki/befriended/141194551) for implementatio of user to user block. When i am filtering blocked users by `withoutBlockingsOf($model)` with leftjoin, getting

```
`"message": "SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'id' in where clause is ambiguous (SQL: select `users`.*, , ROUND(6371 * acos(cos(radians(22.5697)) * cos(radians(`latitude`)) * cos(radians(`longitude`) - radians(88.3697)) + sin(radians(22.5697)) * sin(radians(`latitude`)))) as distance from `users` left join `locations` as `l` on `users`.`id` = `l`.`user_id`  where `role_id` = 2 and `id` not in (691, 686) and `users`.`deleted_at` is null order by `created_at` desc limit 50)" `
```

Without leftJoin, all is ok.

Controller:

```
 User::withoutBlockingsOf($user)
    ->leftJoin('locations as l', 'users.id', '=', 'l.user_id')
    ->select('users.*', DB::raw('ROUND(6371 * acos(cos(radians(' . $lat . ')) * cos(radians(`latitude`)) * cos(radians(`longitude`) - radians(' . $lng . ')) + sin(radians(' . $lat . ')) * sin(radians(`latitude`)))) as distance'))
    ->get();
```

Comment: show you withoutBlockingsOf function?

Comment: @DilipHirapara here it is https://github.com/rennokki/befriended/blob/master/src/Scopes/BlockFilterable.php

Comment: just add 
return $query->whereNotIn($this->getTable().'.'.$this->getKeyName(), $blockingsIds);

in scopeWithoutBlockingsOf function line 18